# Implications of $a_l\not\in\{x_k:k\ge l\}$ where $a_n:=\sup\{x_k:k\ge n\},\forall n\in\mathbf{N}$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, limsup-and-liminf

**Is the following argument correct?**

**Propostition.** Suppose $\{x_n\}$ is bounded sequence, $a_n:=\sup\{x_k:k\ge n\}$ as before. Suppose that for some $l\in\mathbf{N}$, $a_l\not\in\{x_k:k\ge l\}$. Then show that $a_j = a_l$ for all $j\ge l$, and hence $\lim\sup x_n = a_l$.

*Proof.* Let $j\geq l$ and consider that $\{x_k:k\ge l\} = \{x_l,x_{l+1},\dots,x_{j-1}\}\cup\{x_k:k\ge j\}$, thus $\sup\{x_k:k\ge l\} = \max\{\beta,\sup\{x_k:k\ge j\}\}$, where $\beta = \sup\{x_l,x_{l+1},\dots,x_{j-1}\}$, then given our definition of $\{a_n\}$ we have $a_l = \max\{\beta,a_j\}$.

Now evidently $\beta\in\{x_l,x_{l+1},\dots,x_{j-1}\}$, but from hypothesis $a_l\not\in\{x_k:k\ge l\}$, thus $a_l\neq \beta$, thus $\max\{\beta,a_j\}\neq\beta$, consequently $a_l=a_j$, given that our choice of $j\ge l$ was arbitrary it follows that $a_j=a_l,\forall j\ge l$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: What part makes you doubt it's not correct?

Comment: The conclusion of $a_l=a_j$ from $\max\{\beta,a_j\}\neq\beta$.

Comment: If $A$ is a finite set, its true that $\max(A)$ is an element of $A$. Since it cannot be $\beta$, it has to be $a_j$ and if you agree that $a_l = \max\{\beta,a_j\}$ then the conclusion follows

Comment: @user160738 Thanks for clearing that up! much obliged.